# Laravel Eloquent JSON Contains, how to provide WhereIn logic (one of array values)

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

there is my code:

```
protected function room_count($room_count)
{
    $query = $this->builder
        ->whereJsonContains('rent_requests.rooms_count', $room_count);

    return $query;
}
```

There is my filter function. `$room_count` is array, and for example can be `[2,4]`.
`rent_requests.rooms_count` is JSON array in MySQL, and it can be for example `[2,3]`.
I need to filter this, to get this advert showed, but whereJSONContains expects that there will be `2 and 4`, not `2 or 4`.
Is there any tricks to make this function work correctly ? Something like json contains whereIn ?)
Sorry for my english, im really stuck on this, please help me :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MySQL and PostgreSQL support whereJsonContains with multiple values:

So if you are using either of the database then you can pass $room_count as the second parameter

```php
// Room Count Filter
protected function room_count($room_count)
{

    return $this->builder
        ->where(function($query) use($room_count){
     
            $query->whereJsonContains('rent_requests.rooms_count', $room_count[0]);
    
            for($i = 1; $i < count($room_count); $i++) {
               $query->orWhereJsonContains('rent_requests.rooms_count', $room_count[$i]);      
            }
    
            return $query;
      });
}
```

Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses

Comment: sorry i wrote the wrong version of the function.
the original version was exactly that, but it assumes that all array values will be present. but I only need one of the $room_count values present in the JSON Array. i updated the function. is there any way to check, is ONE of $room_count values presented in JSON, not all?

Comment: Does the room_count always have exactly 2 elements/values?

Comment: nope, room_count can be [1, 2, 3, 4], its dynamic. its also can be [1, 2, 3, 4] in the database. as for example $room_count can be [2,4] and database json column can be [4, 3]. i need to get this result with my filters. but when i pass 2,4 to json_contains, it expects that 2 and 4 will be at json, not 2 or 4. this is my problem )

Comment: Okay have updated the answer - try and let me know if it works as per your requirement or not

Answer (score 1):

but @donkarnash function is slightly changed, here is the final version with this example for those who face the same problem

```
 // Room Count Filter
protected function room_count($room_count)
{
    return $this->builder
        ->where(function($query) use($room_count) {

            $query->whereJsonContains('rent_requests.rooms_count', $room_count[0]);

            info (count($room_count));

            for($i = 1; $i <= count($room_count) - 1; $i++) {
                $query->orWhereJsonContains('rent_requests.rooms_count', $room_count[$i]);
            }

            return $query;
        });
}
```

Comment: Good catch - had forgotten to change the variable & column names to match the question context - have updated now